# Remove top/bottom padding from H (heading) tags

Tags: html, css

I've seen lots of posts trying to address this but my padding persists. How (if possible) can you remove the top/bottom padding/margin to to your H1, H2, H3 tags etc.

```css
h1 {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h1>hello world</h1>
```

Comment: By padding do you mean the one on the right? I think it's because of its display property.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify I meant top and bottom padding (have updated title)

Comment: You don't somehow mean the `margin-top` of a paragraph (`<p>`), right? Add a screenshot highlighting the gap you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already removed the top and bottom padding and margin. The space you see above and below the letters in your example is due to the line-height (the default settings depend on your browser). You can reduce that by adding a different setting, but always keep in mind that certain letters need the space above and below, which also depends on the used font which can vary concerning the amount of vertical space needed for these:

```css
h1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>hello - mind letters like these: jQÜØgpÄy</h1>
```

Comment: I'm gonna take the walk of shame on this one. I neglected to consider the spacing is for letters that go below the line of writing, i.e. g y p q

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) in case you are talking about the space above and below the text. Simply pay attention as this is font specific so you may need a different value of `line-height` for another font-family

```css
h1,h2,h3 {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<h1>hello world</h1>
<br>
<h2>hello world</h2>
<br>
<h3>hello world</h3>
```

Comment: But the bottom padding persists.

Comment: @DanielWilliams try lower value of line-height until you get what you want

Comment: That pushes the tag up, but doesn't affect the bottom padding. :-(

Comment: @DanielWilliams what font family are using? can you show us ... it's working fine for me